# Multi-tenancy using Teiid Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, teiid

I am working on a Teiid Spring Boot application and would like to implement Multi-tenant architecture. Teiid Spring Boot is able to connect to two different datasources DS1 and DS2 but as Teiid vdb gets deployed during startup, I have to pass DS1.table_name in my @SelectQuery annotation like below. I don't want to pass DS1 to my query and want to set this value in runtime. Is is possible?

```
@Entity
@SelectQuery(value="select empNo as emp_no, empName as emp_name from DS1.employee")
public class Employee {

    private String empNo;
    private String empName;

    //Getters and Setters

}
```